# My transaction showing up in internal transactions??? How to acquire it?

Tags: myetherwallet, internal-transactions, jaxx

Hello and sorry if this problem is already solved, but i cant find it here unfortunately.

So, my problems started 8 days ago. I've withdrawn my ETH from Bitstamp to friends wallet using MEW and afterwards i've withdrawn to my JAXX wallet. I've already withdrawn numerous times from bitstamp, either to my wallet or to other exchange, so never had problem with any of transactions. This is their warning prior to witdhrawal
Please make sure that the receiving party supports Ethereum transactions generated from smart contracts prior to initiating an ETH withdrawal.

I've seen that MEW and JAXX supports smart contracts so no big deal. But, altough my transactions are checked as success, they never arrived in wallet.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0e658604dd8086aaf3f6b6e1b959820cfc1692b4d37b65374eb9584df179176a
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x084e1aa6bfa2f0ee9b8477ad1255844efb4aed54f5164e2533bfcf2b24a91def

Both of this transactions are in internal transactions of the wallet.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x4af9ccf222277493aae29e5b894d01e78298b1df#internaltx
https://etherscan.io/address/0x24db32e8a937e22f609885a66bf8861a0519b515#internaltx

As you can see, on second link, i've already had internal transactions which was actually shown in my wallet, but not this one (last one - 0.96eth).

I've read about internal transactions now and still not understand what should i do. I've contacted bitstamp support and all they said to me is that funds left their wallet and they are not able to do anything.

Please help me, i am becoming desperate with this. I will send 0.33eth to the guy who help me solve this :(

Comment: Both of those transactions were successful and transferred ether to those destination addresses. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are those addresses (`0x4af9cc...` and `0x24db32...`) not where you expected the ether to be sent?

Comment: they are transfered and succesful, but not showing up on balance. Both adresses are good. First one is from my friends wallet and second one is my jaxx wallet. But if you try to find them in either his, or my wallet, they are not there.

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing up on balance?" Do the balances on etherscan.io look right to you? If so, where do you see the incorrect balances?

Comment: I mean eth was never received. Balance is not good. My jaxx wallet already had 2.12 ETH which you can see when entering my wallet, so i need to have 3.08 with that transaction and same is for my friend. He just didnt got it. I dont understand why is this happening, especially because both wallets support smart contracts.

Comment: Other transactions have happened since. One of the addresses (yours?), `0x24db32`, currently has around 2.12 ether. The 0.97 ether was transferred to it in block 4891176 (5 days, 7 hours ago). But since then, 3.34 ether was transferred in and 14.28 ether were transferred out.

Comment: You are trying to make me crazy, but i am not crazy, if you enter the wallet, you will see there is not any received transaction of 0.96eth and in my friend wallet you will not find 5.12 eth transaction, ETH WERE NEVER RECEIVED AND THE TRANSACTIONS ARE IN INTERNAL TRANSACTIONS WHICH PROOVES MY CONCERN.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the math doesn't add up. You said you already had 2.12 ether, but when? If you had 2.12 ether before the 0.97 was transferred in, then you would have had about 3 ether after the transfer, but after that over 10 ether were transferred out, so surely your balance was higher than 2.12 ether before the transfer.

Comment: The transactions did happen, and the accounts' balances were increased. You can see the transactions in the "internal transactions" tab. That's where Etherscan shows the results of contract calls like this (where neither the transaction's `from` nor `to` address are your account but the transaction has a side effect of transferring ether to you).

Comment: https://gyazo.com/87b408f74684e643973db0933291e195
Do you see any 0.96eth transaction here in wallet? Or you will still try to convince me that i am wrong with my math? These are 1k $ transactions and more, and its not like it is 10$ and i will forget them just like that.

Comment: No, I don't see it in that screenshot. I assume that's from Jaxx? It looks like Jaxx doesn't properly display this sort of transaction. But as long as Jaxx shows the same balance as Etherscan, it's the right balance.

Comment: I know i sound crazy and everything, its probably just stress and paranoia. I really appreciate your help. Dont want to sound arrogant or everything :( I am trying to find out is there any way to see how much ETH someone had in his wallet on some given day? And than start to just calculate. I knew for sure that i had close to zero eth and when i did math, i aggree with you because it was easy for my wallet since there isnt so much transactions. But how can i prove for my friends wallet the same, cause he is having a lot of transactions because he is sending ETH for ico projects.

Comment: Problem solved, i've looked through eth balance checker what was situation before and after my block. Wasnt familiar with that before.

Answer (score 1):

Internal transactions, despite the name "aren't actual transactions", and aren't included directly in the blockchain; they are value transfers that were initiated by executing a smart contract (smart contract ETH transfer).

﻿BitStamp ETH transfers require calling a smart contract to perform the transfer. These show up as internal transactions and are not indicated on the main ETH transaction history when looking for it on etherscan.io. When using BitStamp for withdrawing, you need to make sure that the receiving address supports smart contracts, like MyEtherWallet.

BitStamp deposited ETH into your account. It may be a bit confusing at first, but the transaction was successful and the funds are in your wallet. You can do whatever you want with the ETH in your wallet just as you would normally do.